# AspectJ and NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java

I have problem with [AspectJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ). Has anyone have encountered anything similar? I have listing:

> ../src/java/com/ws/db/Logging.aj
>
> ../src/java/com/ws/db/Db.java

And aspect:

```
  public aspect Logging {

      pointcut prepareCall(String statement): call(* java.sql.Connection.prepareCall(String)) && args(statement) &&
      within(com.ws.db.Db);

      before(String statement) : prepareCall(statement) {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
          logger.debug("before prepareCall called: statement="+statement);
      }

      after(String statement) : prepareCall(statement) {
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
          logger.debug("after prepareCall called, "+statement);
      }
  }
```

Everything works OK, but when I add this

```
   pointcut createStm(): call(* java.sql.Connection.createStatement()) &&
   within(com.ws.db.Db);

   before() : createStm()  {
     if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
       logger.debug("before called: "+thisJoinPoint);
   }

   after() : createStm() {
     if(logger.isDebugEnabled())
       logger.debug("after called: "+thisJoinPoint);
   }
```

I get the following exception:

And it's not able to find com.ws.db.Db, like the class is changed and it's not able to retrieve it.

```
    > org.apache.axis.EXCEPTIONS 2009-11-09 16:06:39,748 -- INFO -- Exception:
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:242)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils$2.run(ClassUtils.java:177)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.loadClass(ClassUtils.java:160)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.ClassUtils.forName(ClassUtils.java:142)
    at org.apache.axis.utils.cache.ClassCache.lookup(ClassCache.java:85)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.getServiceClass(JavaProvider.java:428)
    at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.initServiceDesc(JavaProvider.java:461)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.getInitializedServiceDesc(SOAPService.java:286)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDService.makeNewInstance(WSDDService.java:500)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getNewInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:274)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployableItem.getInstance(WSDDDeployableItem.java:260)
    at org.apache.axis.deployment.wsdd.WSDDDeployment.getService(WSDDDeployment.java:427)
    at org.apache.axis.configuration.FileProvider.getService(FileProvider.java:231)
    at org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.getService(AxisEngine.java:311)
    at org.apache.axis.MessageContext.setTargetService(MessageContext.java:756)
    at org.apache.axis.handlers.http.URLMapper.invoke(URLMapper.java:50)
    at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
    at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
    at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:239)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:709)
    at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:802)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:178)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:126)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:868)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11BaseProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.processConnection(Http11BaseProtocol.java:663)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.PoolTcpEndpoint.processSocket(PoolTcpEndpoint.java:527)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.runIt(LeaderFollowerWorkerThread.java:80)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:684)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interesting difference I see between the examples is that in the one that fails, you're using **thisJoinPoint**.  The class that implements that feature is in the AspectJ runtime library (aspectjrt.jar).  Maybe you don't have that on your webapp's classpath, and the first example succeeded because it didn't need it?